# Como simular uma ação em background para resolver problema de inatividade?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um site em ASP.NET MVC5 na empresa "VaiPapai"(sem merchandising aqui né), essa hospedagem é compartilhada e eu não posso decidir o tempo de inatividade para a sessão cair, no caso como padrão eles colocaram 6 minutos. Isso atualmente é um problema pois eu não posso pagar por um serviço mais personalizado, e eu preciso de sessões mais longas.

É possível através do server side ou do client side simular ações em background, seja qual for para a sessão não cair nesse tempo, seja com o c#(server side) ou javascript(front side) ?

Comment: No client você pode criar uma chamada `Ajax` pra uma operação no server e chamar periodicamente usando `setTimeout` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)  por exemplo, ou no server, criar um método que use um `Timer` (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component) para executar um código que mantenha sua sessão ativa

Comment: Olá,
Precisei fazer isto a um tempo atrás e implementei está solução e para mim funcionou: https://gist.github.com/KyleMit/aa4f576fa32bf36fbedab5540c18211d

Comment: @RicardoPontual Eu utilizei seu método e deu certo ;)